# How do I pass multiple headers to Icinga2 check_http via templates?

Tags: http-headers, icinga2

In Icinga2 hosts.conf, I can add:
    http_header = "HOST: myhost.mycorp.com"

and my check_http sends it as the header.  I want to also add
    http_header = "ACCEPT: */*"

How do I do this syntactically?  On command line for `check_http`, I can add multiple `-k` options.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work in all cases. Pass it as an array:

`http_header = [ "Header1: value1", "Header2: value2"]`

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, figured out that I can add `\n` between two headers and it works with check_http.